# AWS Quicksight/Postgres How to have static columns while the others are filtered by a date range

Tags: postgresql, amazon-quicksight

I have a dataset where I have a list of loan officers and the agents that are affiliated with them. I then have agent stats which I want to be filterable by enroll date. currently if there are no stats within the date range it removes all rows with no stats from the table. I was wondering if there was a way to leave the loan officer name and count of affilated agents columns static while the stats will be filterable by the date range and if there are no stats then it would just show 0 instead of removing the row.

the query for the dataset is as follows:

```
with lo_lead_cte AS (
    select 
    date,
    count(distinct id) as affiliated_lead_count,
    lo_aggregate_id,
    agent_aggregate_id
    from leads_data_v3
    where bank_name = 'P'
    group by date, agent_aggregate_id, lo_aggregate_id
)
select 
paa.*,
llc.date as affiliated_enroll_date,
llc.affiliated_lead_count
from p_affiliated_agents paa
left join lo_lead_cte llc on llc.agent_aggregate_id = paa.agent_aggregate_id and llc.lo_aggregate_id = paa.lo_aggregate_id
```